# Trying to create an endgame chess engine fully on my own in Python. Keeping getting AssertionError: san() and lan() expect move to be legal or null

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-chess

I'm trying to create an endgame chess engine fully on my own and in Python. I'm keeping getting an error as below. I'm unable to get rid of it. Can someone kindly fix it or give me a hint how to fix it?
Or, where is the problem.

```
import chess
import time

def ddfs(board, depth, is_white_turn):
    if board.is_checkmate():
        return True, []
    if depth == 0 or board.is_game_over():
        return False, []
    legal_moves = list(board.legal_moves)
    for move in legal_moves:
        board.push(move)
        found_mate, mate_path = ddfs(board, depth - 1, not is_white_turn)
        board.pop()
        if found_mate:
            return True, [move] + mate_path
    return False, []

def iterative_deepening_dfs(board):
    depth = 0
    while True:
        found_mate, mate_sequence = ddfs(board.copy(), depth, board.turn == chess.WHITE)
        if found_mate:
            return depth, mate_sequence
        depth += 1

def print_move_sequence(board, move_sequence):
    print("Initial board state:")
    print(board, "\n")
    for move in move_sequence:
        if board.is_legal(move):
            board.push(move)
            print(f"Move {board.san(move)}:")
            print(board, "\n")
        else:
            print("An illegal move found in the sequence, which should not happen.")
            break

def main():
    initial_fen = "6k1/8/5K2/2Q5/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1"
    board = chess.Board(initial_fen)

    start_time = time.time()
    mate_depth, mate_sequence = iterative_deepening_dfs(board)
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time

    if mate_depth is not None:
        print(f"Mate found in {mate_depth} move(s), time taken: {elapsed_time:.2f} seconds.")
        board.reset()
        board.set_fen(initial_fen)  # Reset the board to initial state
        print_move_sequence(board, mate_sequence)
    else:
        print("No mate found.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I'm getting this error and cannot get rid of it

```
Mate found in 3 move(s), time taken: 0.00 seconds.

Initial board state:
     . . . . . . k .
     . . . . . . . .
     . . . . . K . .
     . . Q . . . . .
     . . . . . . . .
     . . . . . . . .
     . . . . . . . .
     . . . . . . . . 
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    Cell In[19], line 55
         52         print("No mate found.")
         54 if __name__ == "__main__":
    ---> 55     main()
    
    Cell In[19], line 50, in main()
         48     board.reset()
         49     board.set_fen(initial_fen)  # Reset the board to initial state
    ---> 50     print_move_sequence(board, mate_sequence)
         51 else:
         52     print("No mate found.")
    
    Cell In[19], line 32, in print_move_sequence(board, move_sequence)
         30 if board.is_legal(move):
         31     board.push(move)
    ---> 32     print(f"Move {board.san(move)}:")
         33     print(board, "\n")
         34 else:
    
    File ~\myenvGPU32\Lib\site-packages\chess\__init__.py:2866, in Board.san(self, move)
       2861 def san(self, move: Move) -> str:
       2862     """
       2863     Gets the standard algebraic notation of the given move in the context
       2864     of the current position.
       2865     """
    -> 2866     return self._algebraic(move)
    
    File ~\myenvGPU32\Lib\site-packages\chess\__init__.py:2879, in Board._algebraic(self, move, long)
       2878 def _algebraic(self, move: Move, *, long: bool = False) -> str:
    -> 2879     san = self._algebraic_and_push(move, long=long)
       2880     self.pop()
       2881     return san
    
    File ~\myenvGPU32\Lib\site-packages\chess\__init__.py:2884, in Board._algebraic_and_push(self, move, long)
       2883 def _algebraic_and_push(self, move: Move, *, long: bool = False) -> str:
    -> 2884     san = self._algebraic_without_suffix(move, long=long)
       2886     # Look ahead for check or checkmate.
       2887     self.push(move)
    
    File ~\myenvGPU32\Lib\site-packages\chess\__init__.py:2920, in Board._algebraic_without_suffix(self, move, long)
       2917         return "O-O"
       2919 piece_type = self.piece_type_at(move.from_square)
    -> 2920 assert piece_type, f"san() and lan() expect move to be legal or null, but got {move} in {self.fen()}"
       2921 capture = self.is_capture(move)
       2923 if piece_type == PAWN:
    
    AssertionError: san() and lan() expect move to be legal or null, but got f6g6 in 6k1/8/6K1/2Q5/8/8/8/8 b - - 1 1
```

Comment: Read the error, it says that your last move was illegal. your king can't move to g6.

Comment: @eternal_white This is true but how do I fix my code, it should generate legal moves only.

Comment: It seems that you're asking for debugging help on code you didn't even post.

Comment: @user22758952 oops, sorry. The move f6g6 is only legal if it's the first move and white hasn't moved yet. I've posted an answer, please check it out and lmk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

Print the move (`board.san()`) before you push that move the board with `board.push()`.

---

Just make `board.san()` line before `board.push`.

So the `print_move_sequence(board, move_sequence)` function would be like this:

```py
def print_move_sequence(board, move_sequence):
    print("Initial board state:")
    print(board, "\n")
    for move in move_sequence:
        if board.is_legal(move):
            print(f"Move {board.san(move)}:") # This line should be first.
            board.push(move) # This line shuold be second.
            print(board, "\n")
        else:
            print("An illegal move found in the sequence, which should not happen.")
            break
```

The issue was that when you `push` a move to the board, that move is actually made on the board, and it might sometimes not become legal after it's already executed. In your example, when f6g6 move is executed, it becomes black's turn instead of white. Thus, when doing `board.san()` to see the SAN representation of the move, you won't be able to because it's no longer legal. So the better approach to this is to print the SAN representation before making the move.

Comment: I've copied your code in the place of my function `print_move_sequence` but the error persists! :-(

Comment: @user22758952 are you sure about that? I've tried it many times and it's working. Make sure the old function doesn't exist. Close the file and open it again (or restart the python kernel if you're using Jupyter Notebooks). I'm 100% sure it's working with me. I also put it in colab for you to test it online [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1CQ5GXL3PvACX4tPKraP2EBISASUvJ5pB?usp=sharing).

Comment: What I was aiming for is the move Kh8g7 in this position: `initial_fen = "7K/8/k1P5/7p/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1"` It is the famous Reti endgame for which Kh8g7 is the only move that saves White's Player a Draw.
I attempted to create a variable **stronger = 'black'** which would be used in the subsequent code and that would indicate who aims for draw and who for win. I have dedicated to this problem a considerable amount of tie, but so far I've failed. Could you kindly help me to improve my code along these lines ?

Comment: My current code is [here](https://pastebin.com/m1BQf1qK).

Comment: @user22758952 This is a completely different code than the one provided in the original question , but I'll see it anyways and will send you the working code via pastebin.

Comment: @user22758952 Your new code is very complex. I tried to change many things in it, but it's not working.However, my answer solves your original question, so could you please upvote/mark it as accepted answer and include your newer code in a separate question? Please post your new question link here so I can answer it there.

Comment: You're very kind. I've got stuck with my project. [here](https://pastebin.com/ejVtz8AR) is  my new code. Shall I still create a new question ? Please note what I need most importantly. I want to create a variable seek_for_a_draw = 'white' and seek_for_a_win = 'black' so that white will be satisfied if he can reach a draw while black aims for a win. The code is transparent though not trivial. Feel free to ask me anything about the code.Thank you. BTW, I would like to also print out the number of nodes searched and time elapsed which both should be updated each 1 second printed in time_format

Comment: I'm looking for 64^D boards which should be inserted into A  where D is the number of pieces on the board. I should then propagate_upwards from checkmates and draws using max and min operators with considering "seek_for_a_draw = 'white' and seek_for_a_win = 'black'" and play **fully optimally for both** players. And also consistently update A[1]['up'] = True and also A[1]['moves_to_mate'] = a natural number. No heuristics and no StockFish.

Comment: Alright, I'll make sure to try harder with it tomorrow. Thanks for the upvote and accepting the answer.

Comment: That code above is obsolete so I deleted the link. Last one for you to fix is [here](https://pastebin.com/gN0hSdzS)

Comment: I've noticed that your new code has an infinite while loop in the main function. And it adds up the depth each time it iterates, which makes it take longer time. However, I'm kind of busy these couple days, but I'm confused. Your original code in this question was to see how many moves it can take to have a mate. I'm not an expert in nor chess neither chess engines. However, your new code is more complex and I don't exactly know what you're trying to do. The code that you deleted had a recursion problem because `board.pop()` has some issues in reverting the move (it doesn't fully reverse it).

Comment: By the way, your new code is working fine, but it's taking more time per depth increase. So you want to optimize it?

Comment: I do not care about any kind of optimization. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78023790/chess-endgame-a-problem-with-propagation-upwards-for-a-fully-optimal-game) what I'm trying to accomplish.