# chess endgame: a problem with propagation upwards for a fully optimal game

Tags: python-3.x, chess, python-chess

Can you fulfill all these 13 points at simultaneously:
chess endgame: a problem with propagation upwards for a fully optimal game
I do not know what to add so that my question would become accepted when publishing ?

```
1. include seeking for a draw 
    seeking_draw = {'white': True, 'black': False}

2.GIVE ME A FULL POLISHED EXECUTABLE COMPLETE CODE (without any placeholders) FOR THE ENTIRE PROJECT IN ONE SNIPPET
with the dictionary A included 


3. use this initialization of a  dictionary A:

def initialize_game_tree(initial_fen, stronger):
    """Initializes the game tree with the root node and sets who is stronger."""
    return {
        1: {
            'fen': initial_fen,
            'moves_to_mate': None,
            'parent': None,
            'color': chess.WHITE if is_white_turn(initial_fen) else chess.BLACK,
            'result': None,
            'processed': False,
            'sequence': [],
            'up': False,
        }
    }

4. use these functions

def is_white_turn(fen)
def propagate_results_upwards(game_tree)
def generate_descendants(game_tree, key)
def evaluate_terminal_positions(game_tree)

5. generate all descendants of initial_fen by legal moves

6. do print this on a single line: def format_time(seconds):
    return f"{int(seconds // 3600)}h {(int(seconds) % 3600) // 60}m {seconds % 60:.2f}s"
every 1 second updating it


7. print all searched nodes updated each 1 second on a single line
8. print each new depth, the same depth on a sisngle line, new depth on new line


9. use this
initial_fen = "8/8/2k5/4K3/7p/8/8/8 w - - 0 4"

10. include each new key once only into A

11. 
do include: actual implementations of propagate_results_upwards and evaluate_terminal_positions <consistently> 

def evaluate_terminal_positions(A):
    """Evaluates terminal positions in the game tree A and updates the nodes."""
    for key, node in A.items():
        board = chess.Board(node['fen'])
        if board.is_checkmate():
            # Update node for checkmate
            node['moves_to_mate'] = 0
            node['result'] = 1 if node['color'] == chess.BLACK else 0
            node['processed'] = True
        elif board.is_stalemate() or board.is_insufficient_material() or board.can_claim_draw():
            # Update node for draw
            node['moves_to_mate'] = 0
            node['result'] = 0.5
            node['processed'] = True

12. set node['up'] when there is everything below managed
```

Can you fulfill all these 13 points at simultaneously: chess endgame: a problem with propagation upwards for a fully optimal game I do not know what to add so that my question would become accepted when publishing ?

Comment: There is semi-commercial software that does this by a combination of theorem proving and human guided intelligence. It was the result of someone's PHD thesis on endgame theory about a decade ago. It is called Freezer and although it has its limitations it can do a good job when combined with 6 man tablebases. Working files get very very big and it takes a while to run! It is called [Freezer](https://www.freezerchess.com/index.php?topic=features). NB Everything up to KkXXXXX is available as table bases for perfect endgame play (3,4,5 men ones are now decades old).  7 men ones now ~18TB total.

Comment: @MartinBrown What I was intended was to write **my own code in Python with a few dozens of lines**. I could definitely use StockFish, but that is not my intention. I want to write a simple brand new code on my own, but I didn't succeeded so far.

Comment: @MartinBrown I want to have this outcome upon computing and propagating the flag upwards the tree (obtained by print(A[1]): `  1: {
            'fen': 8/8/2k5/4K3/7p/8/8/8 w - - 0 4,
            'moves_to_mate': 5,
            'parent': None,
            'color': chess.WHITE if is_white_turn(initial_fen) else chess.BLACK,
            'result': 0.5,
            'processed': True,
            'sequence': [],
            'up': True,
        }` **where the sequence would contain all the 5 optimal moves towards the draw**

Comment: by the way, the snippet you provided in this question appears to be your prompt to chatGPT or some LLM, not the code :)

Comment: Keep in mind that making a chess engine or whatever you're trying to do isn't an easy task at all. In fact, it's hard. It's very unfortunate I don't have plenty of time to go deep into this problem. I'd recommend studying some chess engine algorithms and look for research papers that discuss the performance of those algorithms and understand them well before you begin with the code. 


Understanding the problem and how it's solved is much more important that making the solution.

Comment: @eternal_white Yes, it is a prompt to ChatGPT4, but it is keeping me giving wrong answers. Is there a **Python** solution to my original problem, i.e. making an endgame with D=4 pieces on the board **fully** optimal for both B&W player ? I may assume it is W to move and either W is seeking for a draw or for a  win, which condition is known in advance ? How much costs your time for the above project, if I  presumably attract you to some budged in  $ ? My best code attempt is [here](https://pastebin.com/gN0hSdzS)